# Writing a makefile for modular project: Make

Tags: c, gcc, makefile

I am trying to learn makefile and below is my modular project structure:

```
$ pwd
/cygdrive/d/Make/Code
$ ls -R | grep ":$" | sed -e 's/:$//' -e 's/[^-][^\/]*\//--/g' -e 's/^/   /' -e 's/-/|/'
   .
   |-Build
   |-Conversion
   |---bin
   |-----exe
   |-----obj
   |---include
   |---lib
   |---make
   |---source
   |-Main
   |---bin
   |-----exe
   |-----obj
   |---include
   |---lib
   |---make
   |---source
   |-Reverse
   |---bin
   |-----exe
   |-----obj
   |---include
   |---lib
   |---make
   |---source
```

Three modules are 1)Conversion 2)Reverse 3)Main. `makefile` for each these modules are placed in respective `make` folder and they prepare corresponding `.o` files correctly and place them in `bin/obj` of respective folders.

Build directory is for generating the `.exe` file as shown below:

```
$ cat makefile
all:
        cd ../Conversion/make; make
        cd ../Reverse/make; make
        cd ../Main/make; make

Conversion:
        cd ../Conversion/make; make

Reverse:
        cd ../Reverse/make; make

Main:
        cd ../Main/make; make


exeApp:
        cd ../Main/make; make App

cConversion:
        cd ../Conversion/make; make clean

cReverse:
        cd ../Reverse/make; make clean

cMain:
        cd ../Main/make ; make clean

cleanAll:
        cd ../Conversion/make; make clean
        cd ../Reverse/make; make clean
        cd ../Main/make; make clean
```

and the `makefile` for main is:

```
#VPATH= ./../source
INCLUDES= ./../include
OBJDIR= ./../bin/obj
EXEDIR= ./../bin/exe
OBJLOOKDIR= ./../../Conversion/bin/obj:./../../Reverse/bin/obj:./../../Main/bin/obj
#CONBIN= ./../../Conversion/bin/obj
#REVBIN= ./../../Reverse/bin/obj
#MAINBIN= ./../../Main/bin/obj

vpath %.h $(INCLUDES)
vpath %.o $(OBJLOOKDIR)
vpath %.c ./../source

CC= gcc
CFLAGS= -Wall -c -I$(INCLUDES)

OBJECTS= driver.o
PROJECTOBJECTS= binary.o hex.o octal.o reverseNum.o driver.o

main: $(OBJECTS)

driver.o:  driver.c conversion.h
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $(OBJDIR)/$@

App:  $(PROJECTOBJECTS)
        $(CC) -Wall $< -o $(EXEDIR)/$@

clean:
        rm -rf $(OBJDIR)/*.o *~ $(EXEDIR)/*
```

But when I run `make exeApp`, I get below error:

```
$ make exeApp
cd ../Main/make; make App
make[1]: Entering directory '/cygdrive/d/Make/Code/Main/make'
gcc -Wall ./../../Conversion/bin/obj/binary.o -o ./../bin/exe/App
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.8.2/../../../libcygwin.a(libcmain.o): In function `main':
/usr/src/debug/cygwin-1.7.28-2/winsup/cygwin/lib/libcmain.c:39: undefined reference to `WinMain@16'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
makefile:26: recipe for target 'App' failed
make[1]: *** [App] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/cygdrive/d/Make/Code/Main/make'
makefile:17: recipe for target 'exeApp' failed
make: *** [exeApp] Error 2
```

Some how it is not being translated to below rule:

```
$ pwd
/cygdrive/d/Make/Code/Main/make
Gaurav@Gaurav-PC /cygdrive/d/Make/Code/Main/make

$ gcc -Wall ./../../Conversion/bin/obj/binary.o ./../../Conversion/bin/obj/hex.o ./../../Conversion/bin/obj/octal.o ./../../Reverse/bin/obj/reverseNum.o ./../../Main/bin/obj/driver.o -o Trial

Gaurav@Gaurav-PC /cygdrive/d/Make/Code/Main/make
$ ls
makefile  makefileold  Trial.exe
```

as The above rule compiles file, but `exeApp` rule translated only to `gcc -Wall ./../../Conversion/bin/obj/binary.o -o ./../bin/exe/App` . It should have been to `gcc -Wall ./../../Conversion/bin/obj/binary.o ./../../Conversion/bin/obj/hex.o ./../../Conversion/bin/obj/octal.o ./../../Reverse/bin/obj/reverseNum.o ./../../Main/bin/obj/driver.o -o ./../bin/exe/App`

I am not able to figure out why?

Can anyone help, Please.

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure this is your problem, but try replacing all instances of `cd whatever; make` with `$(MAKE) -C whatever`.  (Then read [Recursive Make Considered Harmful](http://miller.emu.id.au/pmiller/books/rmch/) and rewrite your makefiles accordingly.  It will be easier to debug *and* better in the long run.)

Comment: @Zack The problem is `App:  $(PROJECTOBJECTS)
        $(CC) -Wall $< -o $(EXEDIR)/$@` is being translated only to `gcc -Wall ./../../Conversion/bin/obj/binary.o -o ./../bin/exe/App`. with `$<` . i.e. if I replace `App:  $(EXEAPP) 
 $(CC) -Wall  $(EXEAPP)  -o $(EXEDIR)/$@` it works fine.

Comment: @Zack and with `App:  $(EXEAPP)   $(CC) -Wall  $(EXEAPP)  -o $(EXEDIR)/$@` , instead of using `vpath %.o $(OBJLOOKDIR)` I have to give actual path `EXEAPP=  ./../../Conversion/bin/obj/binary.o ./../../Conversion/bin/obj/hex.o\
./../../Conversion/bin/obj/octal.o ./../../Reverse/bin/obj/reverseNum.o \
./../../Main/bin/obj/driver.o`

Comment: @Zack I think I have used `$<` incorrectly in `App:  $(PROJECTOBJECTS)
        $(CC) -Wall $< -o $(EXEDIR)/$@` . Can you please have a look. I am new to `Makefile` . Does `$<` select all dependent files? or just one ? or only `.c` dependents ?

Comment: @Zack Is this kind of rule correct ? `objects= binary.o hex.o octal.o

conversion: $(objects)
 gcc -Wall -o conversion $< -I.` My Makefile is picking only `binary.o` for building `conversion`. I am  expecting `$<` to pick all three `.o` files by such syntax

Comment: `$<` is the *first* dependency only. `$^` does what you expected `$<` to do.  See the [Automatic Variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html) section of the GNU Make manual.  Note that `$^` is *all* the dependencies; for executables, this often includes things that are inappropriate.  Often it is more reliable to have a $(APP_OBJECTS) variable that you put on both the dependency line and the link command line.